# how to make an irregular shaped textview

Tags: android, layout

Is it possible to create a textview that is not square but rather like this:(x=outline of textview)

```
       xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
       x                x
       x                x 
       x                x
xxxxxxxx                x
x                       x
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Comment: or perhaps an answer to my problem would be to place a button view ON TOP of the textview- is that possible?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  Are you wanting text of different sizes, or a view, with text, and other stuff in it?

Comment: I have a textview that the user enters things into and i want a word count on the top left of corner- this word count also be a textview, that is why i left a box in my diagram.

Comment: So this is really 2 text views,  just place one on top of the other, and align the top one to the right of the second one.

Comment: uhhh ya how do you do that- that they cud be on top of each other when i drop one on top of another it just moves next to it

Comment: Use a relative layout, textView1 can be aligned relative to textView2 (this is pretty simple just research how to align views using relative layout).

Comment: why did i get a down vote?

Answer (score -1):

View is a rectangular area on the screen. So you can not make textview or any view with irregular shape. Buy you can make custom view and do your work in onDraw. you can draw on canvas whichever you want but **can not change the shape** public class CustomView extends View {

```
public CustomView(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    //super.onDraw(canvas);
    //Your drawing code here eg.
    //canvas.drawArc(oval, startAngle, sweepAngle, useCenter, paint)
    //canvas.drawCircle(cx, cy, radius, paint);
}
```

}